Can I start a numbered Markdown list with an arbitrary number within SharePoint?
SharePoint has the ability to insert Markdown, which is great!
I have created a numbered list, but I am adding images from my local computer (screenshots). I couldn't find a way to store local images on SharePoint to reference them within Markdown, so I decided to create separate Markdown sections in between the images.
Typically in Markdown, you can start a numbered list with any number. However, SharePoint automatically puts the number as 1 at the start of a new section, even when the raw Markdown says 4 or 6.
Is there a way to start a numbered Markdown list with an arbitrary number within SharePoint?
